User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 98 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php)
After updating to Drupal 10.2.5 and CiviCRM 5.71.2 (or later) under IIS we get many similar errors like:
User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 98 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php).
when managing Drupal People -> Permissions.
Debugging shows that CiviCRM related permissions like "Administer CiviCRM" are involved. Debugging indicates that there are key-value pairs involved where the key is numeric and the value is not an array.
Has anyone else seen the issue? Has anyone any suggestions?

Looks likely related to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29173

@Coleman Many thanks. It is as useful pointer, but I haven't been able to work out from where Drupal gets the 'offending' permissions.
/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Permission/Base.php getAllModulePermissions doesn't get them. <Drupal root.\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\CRM\Core\Permission.php getCorePermissions gets them 'correctly' formatted.

I replaced the 'offending' line in <Drupal root>/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php with a line that logged the $value variable. It turns out that the following Drupal/CiviCRM permissions are the problem:
'view all contacts is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM system is not an array'
'edit all contacts is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM data is not an array'
'edit all contacts is not an array'

I replaced the 'offending' line in <Drupal root>/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php with a line that logged the $value variable. It turns out that the following Drupal/CiviCRM permissions are the problem:
'view all contacts is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM system is not an array'
'edit all contacts is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM is not an array'
'administer CiviCRM data is not an array'
'edit all contacts is not an array'
Notice the duplication. They also appear in the permissions list, so it seems these are extraneous.

@StephenPalmstrom I just started seeing this on a site too - Drupal 10.3.0, Civi 5.74.4, on a LAMP stack.  I've gotten about as far as you have, but wanted to report it's still an issue, and OS/platform is irrelevant

@StephenPalmstrom I log the same permissions you mention in your comment above. There's a new feature of "implied" permissions. Well, it's not new, but new that you can declare them in an extension.  All of these permissions strike me as ones that imply or are implied by other permissions.

@JonG-MegaphoneTech Thanks. Where can we discover these implied permissions? They are obviously not being loaded correctly.
